# What to send the email from CRON Job without writing to file?

Tags: bash, cron

Right now I have a CRON job as shown below,

```
1 * * * * python filename.py | if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then email 'subject' mail@mail.com -c mail1@mail.com ; fi
```

but it sends only the subject to my mail. but I want the error msg from the filename.py i.e body message should contain the error of the file.
one way is to

```
1 * * * * python filename.py  **>> backup_log 2>&1** | if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then email 'subject' mail@mail.com -c mail1@mail.com < **backup_log**; fi
```

But I dont want to write log files...how to send the error msg or best way to do with out log file???

Why if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] condition not working .i.e not mailing if I give wrong python filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mailx to send the mail:

```
python filename.py | mailx -s "Subject" "mail@mail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a FIFO:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mailbody
```

Then modify your crontab:

```
1 * * * * python filename.py  >> 2>&1 /tmp/mailbody | if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then email 'subject' mail@mail.com -c mail1@mail.com < /tmp/mailbody; fi
```

Comment: I just copied the conditional from your original post.. The only thing I changed was the redirect to a FIFO instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error messages are not making it is that error messages are sent to standard error (file descriptor 2) while the pipe only contains standard output (file descriptor 1).

However, you don't actually need this at all; the default behavior of `cron` is to send any output from all jobs by email.  If that is not happening at the moment, check that you set `MAILTO` in your `crontab` file correctly.

```
MAILTO=you@example.com
1 * * * * python filename.py
```

Tangentially, you cannot use `$?` in a pipeline because the exit status of the previous command in the pipeline is not available yet by the time the pipeline is evaluated.

If you want detailed control over when email is being sent, this is not very complex, but decidedly a bit much to put in a single `crontab` line.

```
1 * * * * output=$(python filename.py 2>&1) || echo "$output" | mail -s subject you@example.com
```

The notation `command || othercommand` is simple short-cirtcuit shorthand for `if ! command; then othercommand; fi` (or, if you are not very good at all with shell script, the equivalent anti-pattern `command; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then othercommand; fi`).